# Is there a way to get ffmpeg to continuously output streaming content to s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I have ffmpeg receiving an rtsp stream and its outputting hls files. I want those files to be continuously stored on s3. its not clear how to do this.

I've seen other similar posts but the solutions are always single file outputs piped to the aws cli.  In this case I have an indefinite incoming stream and multiple files to output.

This is what I currently have.

```
   ffmpeg <input stream here>
   -f segment \
   -segment_list_flags live \
   -segment_time 1 \
   -segment_list_size 5 \
   -segment_format mpegts \
   -segment_list public/st/streaming.m3u8 \
   -segment_list_type m3u8 \
   -segment_list_entry_prefix ./ \
   public/st/%d.ts
```

I also have limited space as it will be running in lambda so its not like I can just store the files locally then copy after its done.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use s3fs. Makes the s3 bucket a local folder.

https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse